# How to correctly persist Java Beans?

Tags: java, design-patterns, model, persistence, javabeans

**TL;DR: Is putting persistence methods on the class declaration of a Java Bean wrong or just "ugly"? Also, if it's neither, can I use it with MVC?**

When I first got into Java, I learned that my database tables could be represented in Java as "Beans": a class that has every column (or field) of the table as a member.
I also learned that to persist beans and read rows from a database into said beans, you should use a thing called "DAO": a class that uses the database's rows to make Beans, and uses Beans to make/update rows on the database.

So far, so good.

Fast forward 3-4 years since I learned Java: I'm at college and taking classes on VB.NET (yeah, VB of all things, I know), and my teacher starts teaching about persistence and things like that. I expected her to make something like a Java Bean and a DAO to manipulate those.

Well, she did create something like Java Beans, but instead of creating a DAO, she writes the persistence methods on the Bean itself. And then I thought:

> That actually makes a lot of sense: if you read from the database
>   while on the object, you can actually read the data into the object
>   and return a `boolean` or `int` status to see if the operation you
>   just tried to do worked!
>
> Like: `Person p = new Person().get("James Cameron");`
>   or even: `Person p = new Person(); p.get("James Cameron");`

So I started using this pattern on my Java programs. I felt that my code made more sense, was a lot cleaner and a little faster too.

But something bothered me today: I used the DAO pattern for almost 3 years on everything I coded, and I always felt that it was a bit wrong. I mean, even EJB uses DAOs and EJB is made by the makers of Java, so that should be the correct way to do Bean persistence -- or at least the recommended way. But at the same time it felt clumsy, slow and, to be honest, really tiresome to implement.

So here's my question: Can I put persistence methods inside the Java Bean or that's just plain wrong? And if it's fine to do, what do programmers think about it? I would also love to know if it's acceptable to use it for Models in MVC, because I couldn't find a single thing about it -- and wouldn't know where to start.

Comment: One benefit of having a DAO is that you can have different DAOs for different database providers/dialects. You could have a Db2DAO and a OracleDAO, and you don't have to worry about changing the POJO bean because that is still the same.

Comment: @Brianbcr666Ray If you use a database that has a JDBC compatible driver, then you don't need multiple DAOs: JDBC and the driver provide the abstraction for you. But yeah, I understand what you mean.

Comment: @guilherme.oc97 A bit late, but I just came across this post. When it comes to clean code using a DAO would satisfy SRP (Single-Responsibility-Principle), the Bean stores the data and the DAO takes care of the database operations. But I guess it's mainly a question of taste or as to what extend you want to comply with those principles. I have also come across both ways repeatedly, so I guess either is fine. Just my 2 cents.